# how to call js function from my controller grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm new in grails, it would be good if someone may help me.

I've a js function that I would call in my controller to open a popup after doing some things in controller.

I've this gsp file:

```
<g:form controller="admin" method="post">
<table summary="generer PDF">
..
..
<td>
<g:actionSubmit value="generate" action="genererAction"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</g:form>
```

when the user click at "generate" (button),it must call this function :

```
def generateAction = {
def result
...
if (result){ 
//here, if result=true a popup will be displayed
}
else  {
redirect(action: 'index')
}}
```

I wish you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with ajax, here is an example :

View :

```
<g:form controller="admin" method="post">
<table id="tableID" summary="generer PDF">
..
..
<td>
<!--<g:actionSubmit value="generate" action="genererAction"/>-->
<button onclick="preformAction(); return false;">generate</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</g:form>
```

Controller :

```
def generateAction = {
def result
...
if (result){ 
//here, if result=true a popup will be displayed
render "success"
}
else  {
//redirect(action: 'index')
render "index"
}}
```

Script : // copy this script in your view

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function preformAction(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'${createLink(controller:"admin",action:"generateAction")}', // here you can pass the controller url
        data: {
            // data to be passed to controller
        },
        success : function(response){
            // this block is called after successful processing of controller
            // here you can call your js function after controller has finished its processing
            // consider response has 'success'
            if(response == 'success'){
                 OpenSAGPopup();
            } else if(response == 'index'){
                 window.location = '${createLink(controller:"admin",action:"index")}';
            }

        },
        error : function(response){
            // this block executes if any error occurs with the processing of controller
            alert("Error while generating pdf");
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

try this, if it work let me know....

Happy Coding.

Comment: in my function i would call js function if a specific value is returned;


how can i use this ajax code in this case ?

Comment: excuse me but i don't know where put that code exactly.
i'm not familiar with ajax.

Comment: can you provide your actual code where you want to implement this..??

Comment: i ve update the question, i wish it's more clear now!

Comment: it doesn't work, i'm using a simple window without js or ajax
thank you very much

Comment: you need to include jquery into your code before the script for the code to work.....i have updated the answer....